# Github API Integration in an App

Tags: android, git, github

I want to integrate Github API in an App. But not getting by Github documentaion.
I have normal user account(Free one). please help me.

I want to 
1. Connect to Github API
2. Find the most recent commits (choose at least 25 or more of the commits)

I am not sure 
1. https://api.github.com/ 
2. what would be the second step ?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

you need to get a token, and then use one of the repositories endpoints at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

Comment: Hello, as I am facing the ame problem, I found this thread. I have the token, but where in the query do I put it? Or I need to work with it in a different way. can't find any information on the topic,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to use GitHub API for an unauthorized user. You can authenticate user by using basic authentication, personal token, OAUTH token, OAUTH2 token or by integrating GitHub in app. 
Please check out the GitHub developer documentation for more details - https://developer.github.com/v3/search

I've written an answer on how to use GitHub Search API in an Android App using HTTP request with basic authentication- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238266/5745574

Hope it'll help!! :)