# Connect Android App to Github API

Tags: android, github-api

I've been checking around for some time, but still can't find information on this how exactly to connect my android app to the Github API. I had it registered, had a token as well, read about the endpoints and everything, but cannot understand where the token to be used. May somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Check this video tutorial if it may help -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldmc757EXaE

Comment: Sorry that may be the wrong tutorial, as its for sharing on Github

Comment: Yes, it is for sharing a project on GitHub, there are quite a lot of tutorials of the kind. The only article, a little bit useful so far, is this, but still can't get it http://streamdata.io/blog/github-android-server-sent-events/

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit about what you're trying to do? Are you trying to use a personal access token to access the GitHub API from your app?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do. But finally, I came up to these tutorials, so here the whole process seems to be explained. Thank you :) https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

I've used below code to connect to GitHub Search Repo API in my android app.

---

```
//Method 1: To Authorize API access for all HTTP call
            //Uncomment this part of code and input your username and password
//            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
//                @Override
//                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
//                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
//                }
//            });
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            URL url;
            InputStream inputStream;

            try{
                url = new URL("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q="+"searchText");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//Method 2: To Authorize API access while making HTTP request

                //Uncomment this part of code and input your username and password
//                String basicAuth = "Basic "+Base64.encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);

                //set request type
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                //if you uncomment the following line GitHub API will not respond
//                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                //check for HTTP response
                int httpStatus = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                //if HTTP response is 200 i.e. HTTP_OK read inputstream else read errorstream
                if (httpStatus != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                //print GitHub api hearder data
                    Map<String, List<String>> map = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
                    System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");
                    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey()
                                + " : " + entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                }

                //read inputstream
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String temp,response="";
                while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    response+=temp;
                }

                //GitHub api has limit to access over http. 
                //Api rate limit is 10req/min for unauthenticated user and 30req/min is for authenticated user
                boolean apiLimitExceeded = "false";
                if(response.contains("API rate limit exceeded")){
                    apiLimitExceeded =true;
                }else {
                    //convert data string into JSONObject
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                    JSONArray items = obj.getJSONArray("items");

                    //total result count and result status
                    total_count = obj.getString("total_count");
                    incomplete_results = obj.getString("incomplete_results");
                }

                urlConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Check out my GitHub project to get a complete idea on how to use GitHub search repo API in Android App.
Link: https://github.com/kvipul/Search-GitHub-Repo

There are many filters that GitHub API provides. Check out the Documentation of GitHub search API for more details -https://developer.github.com/v3/search/

Comment: how can i implement this for a private repo

Comment: @theoyuncu8 you mean how to access private repo? I don't think it's possible to access private repos without proper auth. You can authenticate your network calls to access private repos that you already have access to.