# Can github apps like FastHub access private repo?

Tags: github

As I login, it apparently shows the codes in my private repo.
In this case, my private repo is not private anymore?

Comment: If you login, you're logging into github.  So yes, you can see your own private repos.  Check when logged out, or logged in as another user.

Comment: Thanks! I need to delete it then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [FastHub](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub) has your GitHiub login credentials, it stands to reason it can access what you usually can when you log on to github.com directly.

That would include your private repositories.
This is since [issue 56](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub/issues/56) and [commit afaa721](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/FastHub/commit/afaa721f4aa0b5300320ab76462399e952049806).

You can either delete your private repo or (more safely) export it to another Git repository hosting server which accepts private repos (BitBucket, GitLab, ...)

Comment: @nashory Note: deletion is one option, but you can also (before the deletion) export it to another respository hosting service.

Comment: @VonC : I know this is not the right place to ask you (but I don't have any other options), can you please let me know, how would I go upon making a GitHub client app (like fasthub). Does GitHub provide us the APIs for showing the repositories, editing them, etc? What would be the initial step after I do the authentication via GitHub?

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Mainly by calling from your app the GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/, from one of its libraries (https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/) See also https://github.com/streamdataio/github-android. Your application must be registered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502018/6309

Answer (score 0):

The author of FastHub here.

FastHub will list your private repos if GitHub has returned them, basically you could use Access Token to login via FastHub and choose what permissions FastHub has.

Just FYI: FastHub doesn't transfer any data to any where except for Crash Reporting and Firebase analytics (the defaults) so be assured that no data is transferred anywhere :)